# Нужно соединить 3 таблицы в ACL (Audit_command_launguage)

Tags: excel, 1с

У меня есть 3  эксель таблиц и надо написать скрипт который собирает их в одну таблицу формата .FIL и потом извлечь все данные из этих таблиц в отдельную например app_table
Пример первого скрипта который собирает данные в одну таблицу:

```
DIRECTORY "Z:\Scripts\*.xlsx" TO test_table
OPEN test_table
COUNT
Num_of_rec = COUNT1
Counter = 1
DO SCRIPT Appending_script WHILE Counter <= Num_of_rec
CLOSE test_table
```

Код второго скрипта:

```
OPEN test_table
LOCATE RECORD Counter
"Тут нужен скрипт импорта данных из каждой таблицы"
ASSIGN Counter = Counter+1
```

[image: Это одна из пяти таблиц]
[image: Это ожидаемый результат склеивания таблиц]